# check collision between two different custom views whose parents are different

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I have a custom view "Stick", which extends RelativeLayout.
I have another custom view "Ball", which also extends RelativeLayout. And their parents are different. At any time there are multiple(or one) automatically moving balls and sticks in the screen. I want to be informed whenever a ball collides with a stick. Means I want to do something when the collision happens. Currently, I am running an infinite loop to check whether a ball's current bounding rectangle is intersecting with the current sticks bounding rectangle. But it is too costly and if there are multiple sticks and balls in the screen this method doesn't work or barely work. Is there a better way to do it or is there a view collision listener in android?

Below is the stick class

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Stick extends RelativeLayout {

    int height;
    String dest;
    Context context;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    private static int stickDecelerate = 2000;
    private static ArrayList<Stick> stickList = new ArrayList<Stick>();

    public static ArrayList<Stick> getStickList() {
        return stickList;
    }

    public static int getStickDecelerate() {
        return stickDecelerate;
    }

    public static void setStickDecelerate(int stickDecelerate) {
        Stick.stickDecelerate = stickDecelerate;
    }

    public Stick(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public Stick(Context context, int height, String dest, int leftMargin, int topMargin) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.height = height;
        this.dest = dest;

        if(dest.equals("left") || dest.equals("right")){
            layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(height*5, height);
            layoutParams.setMargins(leftMargin-(height*5)/2, topMargin-height/2, 0, 0);
        }
        else{
            layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(height, height*5);
            layoutParams.setMargins(leftMargin-height/2, topMargin-(height*5)/2, 0, 0);
        }
        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    public void release(){
        Stick stick = new Stick(context);
        stick.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        stick.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        this.addView(stick);
        ObjectAnimator animation;
        if(dest.equals("right")) animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(stick, "translationX", GameScreen.getMin());
        else if(dest.equals("left")) animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(stick, "translationX", -GameScreen.getMin());
        else if(dest.equals("up")) animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(stick, "translationY", -GameScreen.getMin());
        else animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(stick, "translationY", GameScreen.getMin());
        animation.setDuration(stickDecelerate);
        animation.start();
        stickList.add(stick);

        animation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                stickList.remove(stick);
                stick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

    }

    public void preview(){

    }

}
```

below is the Ball class

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.Random;

public class Ball extends View{

    int circleBounds;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(circleBounds/4, circleBounds/4, circleBounds/4, paint);
    }

    public Ball(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Ball(Context context, int circleBounds) {
        super(context);
        this.circleBounds = circleBounds;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ballParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(circleBounds/2, circleBounds/2);
        this.setLayoutParams(ballParams);
        startMoving();
    }

    private void startMoving(){
        Random randomAngle = new Random();
        int random = randomAngle.nextInt(360);
        int x = (int) ((int) GameScreen.getMin()*Math.cos(random));
        int y = (int) ((int) GameScreen.getMin()*Math.sin(random));
        ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "x", x);
        ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "y", y);
        long animDuration = (long) (Stick.getStickDecelerate()*2.2);
        animX.setDuration(animDuration);
        animY.setDuration(animDuration);
        AnimatorSet animation = new AnimatorSet();
        animation.playTogether(animX, animY);
        animation.start();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(Important.checkCollision(Ball.this)){
                    animation.cancel();
                    Ball.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
            }
        }, 0);
        animation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                Ball.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and below is the collision check method

```
public static boolean checkCollision(View ball){
    ArrayList<Stick> stickList = Stick.getStickList();
    int[] rec1Pos = new int[2];
    ball.getLocationOnScreen(rec1Pos);
    int v1_w = ball.getWidth();
    int v1_h = ball.getHeight();
    Rect ballBound = new Rect(rec1Pos[0], rec1Pos[1], rec1Pos[0] + v1_w, rec1Pos[1] + v1_h);
    for(Stick stick:stickList){
        int[] rec2Pos = new int[2];
        stick.getLocationOnScreen(rec2Pos);
        int v2_w = stick.getWidth();
        int v2_h = stick.getHeight();
        Rect stickBound = new Rect(rec2Pos[0], rec2Pos[1], rec2Pos[0] + v2_w, rec2Pos[1] + v2_h);
        return ballBound.intersect(stickBound);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, try this boolean method, return true if ball collide.

```
public boolean checkCollision(View ball)
{
    boolean result = false;

    for(Stick stick : Stick.getStickList())
    {
         if(collision(ball, stick))
         {
             result = true;
             break;
         }
         else result = false;
     }

    return result;
}

/*Gets View HitRect*/
public boolean collision(View a, View b)
{
   Rect aRect = new Rect();
   a.getHitRect(aRect);
   Rect bRect = new Rect();
   b.getHitRect(bRect);
   return aRect.intersect(bRect);
}
```

And the `Render()` method of your game:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
 try {
    while (!isInterrupted()) {
         Thread.sleep(100);
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run(){Render();}});}
         }catch (InterruptedException e) {}}};

 t.start();
}

public void Render()
{
    if(checkCollision(ball))
    {
      //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried to get bounding rectangle in this way. But I don't know why it doesn't seem to work. So I had to do it the hard way. And as for the timer, I don't quite understand the difference between timer and handler. Can you please explain a little?

Comment: @ParthaSarker As for the timer that the post is linked to a page that references it, but we go in parts, first edit the method to detect collisions, you will try it and you will tell me if it works

Comment: Can't find any timer.setRepeats method. and it is showing error in the ActionListener()

Comment: @ParthaSarker Well, check my post now, I've edited the code, tell me if the collision works for you

Comment: My problem is fixed but I don't know exactly how. Instead of stick list, I've made a ball list. And Instead of checking collision from the ball, I've checked collision from the stick. Now everything is working fine.

Comment: @ParthaSarker  
I'm glad to know, look, I changed the timer as a cycle by a render method that does the same function, but as you say, with your controller it works, but hey, it was just a suggestion

Comment: okay. I am using your code and game is working like before. Though I would be glad if you tell me the benefits of this process.

Comment: @ParthaSarker The Thread and Handles execute a code constantly, so just use Thread by habit, in terms of collisions, the benefit is that this method requires less code.